# HTML CSS Issue with different clients

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, email-attachments

Hey guys, I have created an html email file and tried sending it out to different browsers and email clients.

Outlook and such are fine but as soon as gmail receives it, all the divisons/tablerows and such go everywhere..

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: All client email are very different. Remember if you put css code in head section, gmail, hotmail & co. do not take it into account.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've had this too. It was due to high air moisture.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this overview: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

As mentioned in the comments and visible in the chart: every email-client does support other Tags...

A few years ago, the best way to achive a good result, was to stick to exremly basic (and old) html and inline css.